# I have Error Substitute

Tags: python, runtime-error, substitution

I have script in Python.

I have errors but sincerely, I don't know why, because , yesterday it worked and now it makes errors ... ( I modified nothing)

I really don't inderstand from where comes these errors.

```
def main( server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path):

  template = open('scriptHmtl.py').read()

  contenu = string.Template(template).substitute(
            code_name = code_name,
            code_version = code_version,
            install_path = install_path,
            os = user_os,
            user_name = user_login
            )


  f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='/tmp/info.html', mode='w', delete=False)
  f.write(contenu)
  f.close()

  webbrowser.open(f.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  server_IP = sys.argv[1]
  code_name = sys.argv[2]
  code_version = sys.argv[3]
  install_path = sys.argv[4]

  user_os = sys.platform
  sys.argv.append(user_os)

  user_login = getpass.getuser()
  sys.argv.append(user_login)

  main(server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path)
```

and the template ( only the form where I have the action ) :

```
<form name="sendData" method="get" action="${server_IP}">
```

errors below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scriptInfo.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(server_IP, code_name, code_version, install_path) 
  File "./scriptInfo.py", line 20, in main
    user_name = user_login
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/string.py", line 172, in substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/string.py", line 162, in convert
    val = mapping[named]
KeyError: 'server_IP'
```

Comment: I use python for my script and I put in my python file an html forms, so, as I said , this code runs since days, but today I wanted to execute my script and I have these errors ...

Comment: The thing is , if I put _user_name_ in comments, others variables in substitute will causes the same error .... I don't understand why it runs and now I have this error .

Comment: I have tested something : I have deleted server_IP variable, but the I have already this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scriptInfo.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(code_name, code_version, install_path) 
  File "./scriptInfo.py", line 20, in main
    user_name = user_login
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/string.py", line 172, in substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/string.py", line 162, in convert
    val = mapping[named]
KeyError: 'server_IP'

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce the problem without knowing how the template looks, particularly what placeholders are defined therein. If it is too long, just post the relevant parts (those with the placeholder).

Comment: @tobias_k, in response to your first comment: I assume you're talking about `user_login`, since there is no `user_name` variable. But since `if` blocks don't have their own unique scope, `user_login` is already at the global scope, so it's visible to `main`. See [this](http://ideone.com/79gCfP) sample script as another example.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, just noticed that myself... thanks for pointing out. I knew this, but just had sort of a brain-freeze I guess... so then the template probably defines a placeholder `$server_IP` which is not given a value in `substitute`.

Comment: I do agree with your "pass it to the `main` function" advice, however. May as well, since you're passing the other four values in.

Comment: the server_IP variable was also in the template (file.py), but if I want to get te server address, do you know how can I do this ?  I have added the party of action in my html form.

Comment: Have you tried adding `server_IP = server_IP,` to the arguments list of `substitute`?

Comment: no is that I would do .... but how retrieve the address of the server after that ? Because, after we click on the ok, the webbrowser say : address not found with http://${server_IP}/cgi/scriptGet.py as URL